# Prove that at least one real root of $ax^2+bx+c$ is in $(0;\sqrt{3}-1)$

Tags: continuity, roots, quadratics, real-numbers, absolute-value

Given that $\left|a\left(b-c\right)\right|>\left|b^2-ca\right|+\left|c^2-ab\right|$ and the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has at least a real root. Prove that at least one real root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is in $(0;\sqrt{3}-1)$.

I tried to solve the problem without success:

Letting $b'=\frac{b}{a}, c'=\frac{c}{a}$, I'm left with $$x^2+b'x+c'=0(1)$$ and $$\left|\left(b'-c'\right)\right|>\left|b'^2-c'\right|+\left|c'^2-b'\right|(2).$$

Since $f(x)=x^2+b'x+c'$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ I decided to prove that $f(0)f(\sqrt{3}-1)<0$, from which $x_0 \in (0;\sqrt{3}-1)$ follows.

From (1) I have $b'^2-4c'\geq 0$. And from (2) I have that $$\left|\left(b'-c'\right)\right|>\left|b'^2+c'^2-b'-c'\right|>\left|b'^2+c'^2\right|-\left|b'+c'\right|,$$ which means $$|b'-c'|+|b'+c'|>|b'^2+c'^2|\Leftrightarrow 2(b'^2+c'^2)>(b'^2+c'^2)^2\Leftrightarrow b'^2+c'^2<2.$$

From this I can deduce a few things like $|b'c'|<1, b'+c'<2$, or even $-2-\sqrt{6}<c'<-2+\sqrt{6}$ but I still can't use them to prove $f(0)f(\sqrt{3}-1)<0$.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: Consider your $b',\,c'$ [inequality plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28x-y%29%3Eabs%28x%5E2-y%29%2Babs%28y%5E2-x%29), maybe it could help to get a more convinient inequality for $b',\,c'$, equivalent to the initial.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'll re-label the variables for convinience, $t:=x,\,x:=\frac{b}{a},\,y:=\frac{c}{a}$ ($a\ne 0$ see **1.** below), so we have
$$|x-y|>|x^2-y|+|y^2-x|,\quad x^2-4y\ge 0.$$
Now I'll open the absolute values signs, yes, considering $8$ possibilities (see **2.** below), to solve the inequality for $x,\,y$ in order to be able to get the picture

[image: 5]

along with the solutions
$$\left[
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{cases}-1<x<0\\ 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}<y<-x\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}0<x<1\\ -\sqrt{-(x - 2) x}<y<-x\end{cases}\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Now the first brace (the upper region) is becoming invalid, because it's given that the equation $t^2+xt+y=0$ has real roots, thus the determinant $x^2-4y\ge 0$ i.e. $y\le \frac{x^2}{4}$, but for $-1<x<0$
$$1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}>\frac{x^2}{4}$$
$$\sqrt{1 - x^2}<1-\frac{x^2}{4}$$
$$4\sqrt{1 - x^2}<4-x^2$$
$$16(1 - x^2)<16-8x^2+x^4$$
$$8x^2+x^4>0$$
Now I'll show that the graph of $y=-\sqrt{-(x - 2) x}$ (for $0<x<1$) is above the line $(\sqrt{3}-1)^2+(\sqrt{3}-1)x+y=0$ that completes the proof as all the valid inequality solutions will be inside the region of $\left((\sqrt{3}-1)^2+(\sqrt{3}-1)x+y\right)y<0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(\sqrt{3}-1)\cdot f(0)<0$ for the $f$ defined in the OP.

[image: 6]

$$-\sqrt{-(x - 2) x}>-\left((\sqrt{3}-1)^2+(\sqrt{3}-1)x\right)$$
$$\sqrt{-(x - 2) x}<(\sqrt{3}-1)\left((\sqrt{3}-1)+x\right)$$
$$-(x - 2) x<(\sqrt{3}-1)^2\left((\sqrt{3}-1)+x\right)^2$$
[$$2 x - x^2<-2 \sqrt{3} x^2 + 4 x^2 + 12 \sqrt{3} x - 20 x - 16 \sqrt{3} + 28$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28x+-+2%29+x%3C%28%5Csqrt%7B3%7D-1%29%5E2%5Cleft%28%28%5Csqrt%7B3%7D-1%29%2Bx%5Cright%29%5E2)
$$(5-2 \sqrt{3})x^2+(12 \sqrt{3}-22)x- 16 \sqrt{3} + 28>0$$
$$\frac{D}{4}=(6 \sqrt{3}-11)^2-(5-2 \sqrt{3})(-16 \sqrt{3} + 28)=$$
[$$4 \sqrt{3} - 7<0,$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286+%5Csqrt%7B3%7D-11%29%5E2-%285-2+%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%28-16+%5Csqrt%7B3%7D+%2B+28%29)
as $(5-2 \sqrt{3})>0$ so all the parabola is above $y=0$ (because no intersections), QED.

---

1. Consider $a=0$ separately to divide by $a\ne 0$ later:
   $$0>|b^2|+|c^2|$$
   $$\emptyset$$

---

2. 

$$
\hbox{1) }\begin{cases}
x−y\ge 0\\
x^2−y\ge 0\\
y^2−x\ge 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{2) }\begin{cases}
x−y< 0\\
x^2−y\ge 0\\
y^2−x\ge 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{3) }\begin{cases}
x−y\ge 0\\
x^2−y< 0\\
y^2−x\ge 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{4) }\begin{cases}
x−y< 0\\
x^2−y< 0\\
y^2−x\ge 0\\
\end{cases}\\
\hbox{5) }\begin{cases}
x−y\ge 0\\
x^2−y\ge 0\\
y^2−x< 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{6) }\begin{cases}
x−y< 0\\
x^2−y\ge 0\\
y^2−x< 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{7) }\begin{cases}
x−y\ge 0\\
x^2−y< 0\\
y^2−x< 0\\
\end{cases}\quad
\hbox{8) }\begin{cases}
x−y< 0\\
x^2−y< 0\\
y^2−x< 0\\
\end{cases}$$
[image: 7]

$$\hbox{1) }(x-y)>(x^2-y)+(y^2-x)$$
$$y^2 + x^2-2 x+1<1$$
$$y^2 + (x-1)^2<1$$
$$\hbox{2) }-(x−y)>(x^2−y)+(y^2−x)$$
$$x^2 + y^2-2y+1<1$$
$$x^2 + (y-1)^2<1$$
$$\hbox{4) }-(x−y)>-(x^2−y)+(y^2−x)$$
$$(y - x) (x + y)<0$$
$$\hbox{5) }(x−y)>(x^2−y)-(y^2−x)$$
$$(y - x) (x + y)>0$$
$$\hbox{7) }(x−y)>-(x^2−y)-(y^2−x)$$
$$x^2 + y^2-2y+1>1$$
$$x^2 + (y-1)^2>1$$
$$\emptyset$$
$$\hbox{8) }-(x−y)>-(x^2−y)-(y^2−x)$$
$$x^2-2x+1 + y^2>1$$
$$(x-1)^2 + y^2>1$$
$$\emptyset$$
[image: 8]